# Transform List (Generator a) into Generator (List a)

Tags: functional-programming, elm

Here is a simplified version of my problem: Generate a list of random values in which each consecutive value depends on the previous one.

For example, generate a list of random `Int`, in which each consecutive value will establish minimum for the next step. Let's assume that starting `value = 0` and maximum value is always `currentValue + 5` :

1. First step: `Random.int 0 5` => 3
2. Next: `Random.int 3 8` => 4
3. Next: `Random.int 4 9` => 8
4. etc.

Here is my approach:

```
intGen : Int -> List (Rnd.Generator Int) -> List (Rnd.Generator Int)
intGen value list =
  if length list == 10 then
    list
  else
    let newValue = Rnd.int value (value + 5)
        newList = newValue :: list
    in intGen newValue newList
```

Let's transform it into `Rnd.Generator (List Int)`:

```
listToGen : List (Rnd.Generator Int) -> Rnd.Generator (List Int)
listToGen list =
  foldr
    (Rnd.map2 (::))
    (Rnd.list 0 (Rnd.int 0 1))
    list
```

I don't like this part: `(Rnd.list 0 (Rnd.int 0 1))`. It generates initial   value of type `Rnd.Generator (List Int)`, in which `(Rnd.int 0 1)` is actually never used but is needed by type checking. I would like to skip this part somehow or replace it with something more generic. Is it possible or my implementation is erroneous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one solution which uses `andThen` and `map`. The first parameters is the number of elements you want in the list. The second parameter is the starting value.

```elm
intGen : Int -> Int -> Rnd.Generator (List Int)
intGen num value =
    if num <= 0 then
        constant []
    else
        Rnd.int value (value + 5)
            |> Rnd.andThen (\i -> intGen (num-1) i
            |> Rnd.map (\rest -> i :: rest))
```

To match your example of a list of size 10 starting with 0 as the first low value, you would call this as `intGen 10 0`.

`constant` is a generator from [`elm-community/random-extra`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/random-extra/2.0.0/Random-Extra#constant), or it can be defined simply like this (because it isn't exposed in the core Elm codebase):

```elm
constant : a -> Rnd.Generator a
constant a = Rnd.map (\_ -> a) (Rnd.int 0 1)
```

Regarding your example, I don't think you would want to use `List (Rnd.Generator Int)` because that implies a list of generators that aren't tied together in any way. That's why we need to use `andThen` to pull out the random value just generated, call `intGen` recursively minus one, then use `map` to put the list together.

Comment: I was thinking about something similar. Moreover, `random-extra` package has also `List (Generator a) -> Generator (List a)` function, so I guess it's good to know community packages ;-). Thanks!